# Ошибка в SQL-запросе: invalid column name 'RN'

Tags: sql

Ошибка при выполнении запроса: `invalid column name 'RN'`. Если убрать условие `RN=1`, то запрос выполняется и ранжируется по полю `ac_app_id`. Возможно ошибка в синтаксисе `ROW_NUMBER() over(функцию включила для выявления дублей и по ac_app_id)`

```sql
select AC_APP_ID,AC_open_dt,CRS_Product,  sum(convert (float,AC_loan_amount)),

ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CRS_Product order by AC_APP_ID  desc)  [RN]

from bd.schema.table1 fa (nolock)

join bd.schema.table2 (NOLOCK)  rs on fa.AC_APP_ID=rs.CRS_APP_ID

where eomonth(ac_open_dt)>='2020-06-30'  and CRS_Product like ('Продукт%') and ac_app_id=60001

and RN =1

group by AC_APP_ID,ac_open_dt,CRS_Product

order by 1 ,2
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что вам нужно вместо `and RN =1` добавить `having RN =1` между `group by` и `order by`

Comment: ROW_NUMBER должно быть в подзапросе, а  where RN=1 во внешнем запросе. Алиасы колонок в запросе видны только в order by.